# Add 20 general purpose computer objects at once

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add 20 general purpose computer objects to my sub ou Abbottsfield that is a sub ou of branches. I know how to create 1 new computer at a time but would like to be able to add 20 at once. Not sure how to do this

any help would be appreciated

Here is what I put in powershell to add one new computer

```
New-ADComputer -Name "abbots-1" -Path "OU=Abbottsfield,OU=Branches,DC=company,DC=epl,DC=local"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a array **@()** and put 20 integers in it **0..19**
Then Pipe it **|** and run the piped variable **$_** to the command

```
@(0..19) | New-ADComputer -Name "abbots-$_" `
    -Path "OU=Abbottsfield,OU=Branches,DC=company,DC=epl,DC=local"
```

I added a ` in order to split command to make it more readable.

This will create 20 computers named from abbots-0 to abbots-19